# Intent Between different classes/methods

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, spinner

I want to send 2 different values to the InformationActivity.
 Firstly: I want to send the barcode number, and a list (which works correctly). But for some reason the list that i send (wheat or crus or eggs depending on what i press) doesnt appear in the InformationActivity.
 I think that the problem is because it is in 2 different classes. 
 How I could change the code so that it sends both the barcode string and one of the lists into the next activity?

PS. I tried declaring intent as a global variable and that crashes the app
PSS. at the moment I am just testing it by printing i item in that array.

Main:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private Button buttonLogout;
private ZXingScannerView scannerView;
private final int permission_code = 1;

Spinner spinner;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }
    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    //android spinner to select profile
    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerProfiles);
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.restrictions, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item + " Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InformationActivity.class);
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    String[] wheat = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Wheat);
                    intent.putExtra("Profile", wheat);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    String[] crus = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Crustaceans);
                    intent.putExtra("Profile", crus);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    String[] eggs = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Eggs);
                    intent.putExtra("Profile", eggs);
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            return;
        }
    });

}


//opens camera when button is pressed
public void scanBarcode(View view) {
    //check if user given app camera permissions
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, permission_code);

    }
    //opens camera
    scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
    scannerView.setResultHandler(new ZXingScannerResultHandler());
    //stops camera and scannerview
    setContentView(scannerView);
    scannerView.startCamera();

}

//stops camera and outputs barcode result to a Toast
class ZXingScannerResultHandler implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result result) {
        String resultBarcode = result.getText();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InformationActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("barcode", resultBarcode.toString());
        startActivity(intent);
        scannerView.stopCamera();
    }
}
```

InformationActivity:

```
public class InformationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_information);

    TextView barcodeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBarcode);
    barcodeView.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("barcode"));

    TextView profileView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvProfile);
    String[] Profile = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("Profile");
    profileView.setText(Profile[1]);


}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `onItemSelected()` method is adding a `String[]` to an `Intent` object, but then just throwing that `Intent` away.

> ```
> @Override
> public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
>     ...
>     Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InformationActivity.class);
>     switch (position){
>         case 0:
>             String[] wheat = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Wheat);
>             intent.putExtra("Profile", wheat);
>             break;
>         case 1:
>             String[] crus = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Crustaceans);
>             intent.putExtra("Profile", crus);
>             break;
>         case 2:
>             String[] eggs = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Eggs);
>             intent.putExtra("Profile", eggs);
>             break;
>     }
> }
> ```

Later on, you start the activity with a *different* `Intent`:

> ```
> @Override
> public void handleResult(Result result) {
>     String resultBarcode = result.getText();
>     Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InformationActivity.class);
>     intent.putExtra("barcode", resultBarcode.toString());
>     startActivity(intent);
>     scannerView.stopCamera();
> }
> ```

It's important to understand that these two intents are **not** shared somehow; the first one is completely separate from the second, and as soon as `onItemSelected()` finishes executing, the intent is thrown away.

What you should do is change your `onItemSelected()` method so that it stores information about the selection somehow (maybe update  a variable in your activity), and then change your `handleResult()` method to read that saved information and add the array to the intent. Maybe something like this:

```
String[] selectedArray;
```

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    ...
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            selectedArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Wheat);
            break;
        case 1:
            selectedArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Crustaceans);
            break;
        case 2:
            selectedArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Eggs);
            break;
    }
}
```

```
@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
    String resultBarcode = result.getText();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InformationActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("barcode", resultBarcode.toString());
    intent.putExtra("Profile", selectedArray);
    startActivity(intent);
    scannerView.stopCamera();
}
```

Comment: I had an Idea what was wrong but I'm a complete beginner and had no clue how to fix it. Was looking for a solution for the last 5 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [startActivityForResult()](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html?hl=EN) for better management of your information exchange between your activities and build a more solid app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call scanBarcode() function to fire the intent and launch InformationActivity using the perfect solution provided by Ben:

```
String[] selectedArray;
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    ...
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            selectedArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.name);
            break;
        case 1:
            selectedArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.name);
            break;
    }
}
```

Also simply call finish(); function in onBackPressed() of InformationActivity to navigate to Mainactivity :

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.finish(); // or use super.onBackPressed(); 
}
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: When I call finish() on InformationActivity the app brings me back to the "scannerView" how could I avoid this, i think its onResume but Im not too sure how to implement it